# How can I find where node.js is running?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a VPS with node.js installed, I already uploaded a basic example to test it on the server, so I tried doing this:

I access by SSH, navigate to my project folder and run

node app.js

I get this message

Express server listening on port 8080

I thought i could see my app here

example.com:8080 or server.example:8080... but nothing. Then I tried with the info from os.networkInterfaces(); and os.host(); and still nothing happen

could you help me out? as you can see I am a total noob on node.js. What I'm doing wrong? or what should I do before running my app? Something related to DNS's? i have no idea

Comment: check your vps settings, you may need to open port 8080. Try using port 80 and the server ip address (not DNS name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone ever has the same problem this is how i solved on CentOS:

Open this file

```
 / Etc / csf / csf.conf
```

Add the required port

Allow incoming TCP ports

```
TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,26"
```

Allow outgoing TCP ports

```
TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,25,37,43,53,80,110,113,443,587,873"
```

Restart

```
 # # Csf-r
```

Comment: i think it will be better to clarify, for what exactly linux distributions this command are written. For example, on Centos you can use this commands to tune firewall to work with nodejs https://github.com/vodolaz095/hunt/blob/master/examples/serverConfigsExamples/firewall.sh

Answer (score 1):

How do you ssh to your host? with ip or name? Is it something like:

```
ssh root@example.com
```

if so then at least you know your DNS is ok.

Once on the server do a

```
netstat -a
```

if you find *:8080 then your server is listening in the default ip. If you see something like 12.23.45.67:8080 then this number is the ip your server is listening.

```
ifconfig
```

will give you the servers ip. This should be the same as the ip of example.com. If not then maybe there is some router/firewall in front of your server and you have to configure that to allow port 8080 to reach your server.